# Nullable object must have value Exception

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

I am a newcomer in CRM 2011 plugins. I wrote a plugin to update the tax value. But at the line below it throws the error

> "Nullable object must have value"

```
double Tax = (double)(QuoteProduct.BaseAmount - QuoteProduct.ManualDiscountAmount - 
             QuoteProduct.VolumeDiscountAmount) / 20;
```

When the error occurs, the values are: 
Base amount = 0, 
manual discount amount = null, 
volume discount amount = 0

Comment: To declare more, at the level the error occurs the values are: Base amount = 0, manual discount amount = null, volume discount amount = 0

Comment: check GetValueOrDefault method

Comment: Which tax do you expect when one amount is `null`? Do you want to use zero in place of `null`? Or do you want your result to be `null`?

Comment: I want to result be zero.

Comment: What are the types of `BaseAmount`, `ManualDiscountAmount`, and `VolumeDiscountAmount`? Are they all nullable `double` (`double?`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming all your variables are of the type `Nullable<T>`, you can use the `GetValueOrDefault`() method ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0.aspx) article).

The method will either return the value that the object has or in case of null return the default value for that type (0.0 for double).

```
double Tax = (double)(QuoteProduct.BaseAmount.GetValueOrDefault() - QuoteProduct.ManualDiscountAmount.GetValueOrDefault() - 
             QuoteProduct.VolumeDiscountAmount.GetValueOrDefault()) / 20;
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I've used your method, but it throws exception at savechanges line:             var QuoteProduct = crm.QuoteDetailSet.Where(c => c.QuoteDetailId == QPID).First();
            double Tax = (double)((QuoteProduct.BaseAmount - QuoteProduct.ManualDiscountAmount.GetValueOrDefault() - QuoteProduct.VolumeDiscountAmount.GetValueOrDefault()) / 20);
            QuoteProduct.Attributes["tax"] = Tax;
            crm.UpdateObject(QuoteProduct);
            crm.SaveChanges();

Comment: Please share the details of the exception - or maybe ask a separate question so that more people can help

Comment: Ok! Thanks. I am going to ask another question.

Comment: Instead of `QuoteProduct.BaseAmount.GetValueOrDefault()` one can also use `(QuoteProduct.BaseAmount ?? 0.0)`. But be careful with parentheses when using the `??` operator together with e.g. minus (binary `-` operator).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Why? I though that denullifying operator (*??*) bound stronger than subtraction operator (*-*)...

Comment: @KonradViltersten:http://en.csharp-online.net/ECMA-334%3a_14.2.1_Operator_precedence_and_associativity. It is just above conditional operators

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Well, I'll be darned. Is it really **that** low?! I guess I stand corrected. Still, it **should** be higher up, IM-not-so-HO.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Yes, but you will have to update your own answer with some parentheses.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I stubbornly refuse to clog the code with brackets! Never the less, you have a valid point (the code **was** faulty, in a very sneaky way), so I fixed it. But note - no brackets! Thanks a lot, by the way. (I) (dislike) (brackets) ()... :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cast null to double.

```
double x = null;
```

Produces the error:

> Cannot convert null to 'double' because it is a non-nullable value type

So you have to make sure that your values are 0 (zero) and not null.

Comment: It's CRM. Most of the values will be nullable, so it's `double? x = null;` in most cases. Or rather `decimal? x = null;`.

Comment: CRM or not: He tries do to double tax = (double)(null); which won't work in C#.

Comment: Correct. I only mean that the correction in this particular case should be changing *double* to *double?*. The *null* value is correct. It's the receiving variable that's of wrong type. So I wasn't correcting you - rather extending your reply.

Answer (score 2):

You cant subtract from null!

```
if (... != null)
```

Answer (score 1):

I recognize the formulation from the other post you made. Usually, in such situation I use a nice syntax as follows. (The syntax of *GetValueOrDefault* mentioned by the other replier is OK but tends to make your code less readable and the lines *waaay* to long.)

Consider the following change (I'm assuming that every part can happen to be be *null*.

```
decimal tax = QuoteProduct.BaseAmount ?? 0;
tax -= QuoteProduct.ManualDiscountAmount ?? 0;
tax -= QuoteProduct.VolumeDiscountAmount ?? 0;
QuoteProduct.Attribute["tax"] = tax / 20;
```

(I'm assuming that this is related to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320363/unhandled-exception-on-savechanges-crm-2011-plugin).)

Comment: If the amounts are nullable `double`, then `tax` must be `double` (not `decimal`). Otherwise I like using the `??` operator.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Correct. But I'm fairly sure that his values are *decimal* if not *Money*. CRM is a bit backwards that way, in my opinion. I like you nit-picky-ness. Keeps me off giving sort-of-working code in the examples. Thanks!