# Unhandled exception on SaveChanges CRM 2011 plugin

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a problem in my CRM 2011 plugin.

```
var QuoteProduct = crm.QuoteDetailSet.Where(c 
  => c.QuoteDetailId == QPID).First();
double Tax = (double)(
  (QuoteProduct.BaseAmount 
    - QuoteProduct.ManualDiscountAmount.GetValueOrDefault() 
    - QuoteProduct.VolumeDiscountAmount.GetValueOrDefault()) / 20);
QuoteProduct.Attributes["tax"] = Tax;
crm.UpdateObject(QuoteProduct);
crm.SaveChanges();
```

The error occurs on the save changes line. The error details are as follows.

> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.SaveChangesException was unhandled by user code
>     Message=An error occured while processing this request.
>     Source=Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk
>     StackTrace:
>       at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions options)
>       at Plugin.TaxCreator(IOrganizationService service, Guid QPID) in C:\Users\mycrm\Desktop\BMSD.QuoteProduct.Tax\BMSD.QuoteProduct.Tax\BMSD.QuoteProduct.Tax.cs:line 62
>       at Plugin.Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) in C:\Users\mycrm\Desktop\BMSD.QuoteProduct.Tax\BMSD.QuoteProduct.Tax\BMSD.QuoteProduct.Tax.cs:line 38
>       at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.V5PluginProxyStep.ExecuteInternal(PipelineExecutionContext context)
>          at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
>     InnerException: System.ServiceModel.FaultException
>          Message=System.InvalidCastException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #BE061894
>          Source=Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility
>          StackTrace:
>               at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.Execute(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType)
>               at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InprocessServiceProxy.ExecuteCore(OrganizationRequest request)
>               at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext.Execute(OrganizationRequest request)
>               at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext.SaveChange(OrganizationRequest request, IList`1 results)
>          InnerException:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your stack trace there is a `System.InvalidCastException`

It means value of some attribute has incorrect type. Since you are changing only 'tax' attribute, then its type is incorrect. Most probably "tax" is a Money field, so I guess you should assign variable of type `decimal` to it, not `double`. Try something like this:

```
decimal Tax = (decimal)((QuoteProduct.BaseAmount 
  - QuoteProduct.ManualDiscountAmount.GetValueOrDefault() 
  - QuoteProduct.VolumeDiscountAmount.GetValueOrDefault()) / 20);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sergey. Since I am new in these subjects my question could be look foolish!

Comment: @PaymanBiukaghazadeh No, it didn't. The only thing that you might consider improving in your question is the formatting. I've done that for you this time but you might get a better response in the future if you format the question beautifully. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information presented, it's probably conversion problem when you cast to double. The problem is that CRM by default presents reals with a higher precision than what you try to box it into.

- *double* is 8 bytes tall and holds significance of 15 digits
- *decimal* is 12 bytes tall and holds significance of 28 digits

So, even though the actual value you're handling would fit in any of them (and *double* is de facto standard for non-integers in C#), the computer reacts and gives you a warning that you're putting something (potentially) really big into a (relatively) small hole.

You need to redeclare the *tax* as follows.

```
//double tax;
decimal tax = QuoteProduct.BaseAmount 
  - QuoteProduct.ManualDiscountAmount.GetValueOrDefault() 
  - QuoteProduct.VolumeDiscountAmount.GetValueOrDefault();
QuoteProduct.Attributes["tax"] = tax / 20;
```

Or you could manually convert the *decimal* values to *double* using the built-in converting classes. However, given that you're putting the result into a field (that surely manages *decimal* type), it's an unnecessary detour in my opinion.

You can read more on the different type [by clicking here](http://bit.ly/ZukocH).